# How to login windows remote desktop (RDP) in windows 11 when Microsoft account and Hello Pin enabled?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

I have googled this 10 hours without finding any useful working solutions. I just fresh installed Windows 11. During the installation, it forces me to use Microsoft account and Windows Hello Pin. And some services also require Hello Pin. Thus I can not disable it.

Now, when I try to use remote desktop, there is a problem. I can not connect. I have no ideas what causes the connection failure. I even not sure what my username is. Is Pin the password? I don't have any password actually. Even microsoft acount web login is using one time password sent to my email. Do I need to provide `domain` infomartion?

I tried username `mylongusername@gmail.com`, `PCNAME\mylon`, `mylon`, `Administrator` because `mylong` is my user folder.

I have no ideas what the password is, so I used my Windows Hello Pin.

So far, I have made RDP work by simply disabling Windows Hello Pin.

I have no ideas why Microsoft invents something which does NOT work at all. Especially, Hello Pin is forced to be enabled during installation process and shows as recommended sign-in option in the settings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On a fresh install of Windows 11, password use is disabled.

You can easily enable passwords and that will likely help you on the machine you are trying to RDP into because you will be able to use your password.

Then you can use your Microsoft Account.

See the screen shot with the appropriate settings.

Uncheck the security setting shown.

[image: Enable Passwords]

Logout and login with password (not PIN) at least once before RDP access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the same step to disable Windows Hello Pin. Can we use Windows Hello Pin and Password at the same time? Thanks.

Comment: When you change the setting above, you can use PIN or Password (but one or the other at any point in time).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is exactly what I did in my question description. Nothing really new. For me, I want to have both password and PIN at the same time, because some of windows services require PIN to work. Cheers.

Comment: Generally for login or remote access you are best to choose which way. It may be possible to use PIN after the password. You would need to experiment. I commonly use password except for my own computer log in.

Comment: The above option seems to be disable in my case while connecting over remote desktop. For me the initial login works, but in case the session was locked, I am unable to reconnect. I need to close the session and reopen is.

Comment: The last sentence made me try logging in with my password after enabling RDP and that was apparently the issue.

Comment: As per @stringsn88keys comment, it was logout and login with password on my local machine that got RDP working.  While I had both PIN and Password enabled on my local machine I had only ever previously used the PIN.  Using the Password once to log in allowed me to authenticate to RDP.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You can try my case - the computer is connected with MS account and enable MFA. , no need to Uncheck the security setting, keep the PIN and also the MFA. So there are some steps and tricks.
Let’s say:

- namle-zenbook: the remote computer
- namle-az: the Local Account username on the remote computer
- le***@li**.com: the Microsoft Account username on the remote computer

1. Enable Remote Desktop on the Computer that you want to remote.
2. On that remote computer, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   to open 'Run' and use the Runas command by entering `runas /u:MicrosoftAccount\your@email.com cmd.exe`
3. A Command Prompt will be shown, type your current Microsoft Account password and enter.

Now, you can connect to that computer via Remote Desktop.

We can use both Local Account user (ex: namle-az) and Microsoft Account username (ex: le***@li**.com), with password is the current Microsoft Account password.

[image]

You can find the detail here https://nready.net/remote-desktop-on-windows-11-with-microsoft-account-mfa/

Comment: I wish this were the selected answer. It's much better than needing to turn off Hello. However, I had to go to the article to get the suggestion to work. The runas command shown in this answer is truncated. It should be: runas /u:MicrosoftAccount\your@email.com cmd.exe

Comment: Can you explain what happened here? Your method worked and I upvoted already. But want to know the sorcery underneath.

Answer (score 6):

Just login with your microsoft account password at least once on the target pc!

Credit where credit is due:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/comments/1117520/view.html

Br

Comment: This is the correct answer. Disable the Windows Hello sign-in. Login with your password. Enable the Windows Hello sign -in. You can now RDP using a password while having pin enabled.

Comment: +1 I couldn't get anything to work until trying this!

Comment: Actually, this does the same as the answer suggested by @Nam-Le. Both work.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem. Nothing worked.
I resolved this by disabling my PIN (I also had all the other smart unlocks disabled). And then I was able to remote in.
I then re-enabled my PIN and everything still worked.

The username used was my email address and password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Windows 11 - same issue; no local password as Windows was defaulting to a Microsoft account email login, hence no credentials to log in remotely.

Here are the steps I used to resolve this:

Get user id:

1. Win + R --> Type "cmd" [enter] --> Type "whoami" [enter]
2. This should show you your userid

Get password:

1. Click on Windows Icon
2. Click on User -> Change Account Settings
3. In Account settings, choose "Sign in with local account" (instead of a Microsoft account)
4. This should prompt you to create a local password instead of using Windows Hellol, Pin, or whatever

You now have your local userid and password!

A bit frustrating that Microsoft seem to only give you the option of an either/or for local account or microsoft account!

Answer (score 1):

Your Microsoft account has a password. It is what you set when you created it. If you go to https://account.microsoft.com and you enter your emailaddress as username, you then use a password to login to your microsoft account. This webpage also has options to reset it in case you forgot your account.

Once you know your password there, you can use mylon with that password to use RDP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the 'passwordless' login on your MS account online.
Log in online, go to security, security dashboard, advanced security options, then turn off 'passwordless account'
It will ask you to create a new password. Set this.

Lock your device (that you want to access via RDP), and select forgot PIN. It will ask for your password and MFA. Then ask to set a new PIN, and click cancel. Now your Device has cached your password, RDP will work!!!